# How to pass QString or QStringList to QTableWidgetItem

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I am trying to create a table using `QTableView` and `QTableWidgetItem`.

Basically I am trying to create a few rows with some name under first Header.

But the problem is I am passing each row with some name.

Same thing I want to achieve using `QString`, `QStringList` array.

Currently I am not passing any value under second header.

Please suggest how to do that. Please find the output window.

Below is my code snippet:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QString>

#define ROW_NUMBER 20
#define COL_NUMBER 2

int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv); 

    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();

    window->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("TableWidget Resize column width"));
    window->resize(200,250);

    QTableWidget *table = new QTableWidget();
    table->setRowCount(ROW_NUMBER);
    table->setColumnCount(COL_NUMBER);

    table->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);

    table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("Field;Value").split(";"));

    table->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem("Sequence Number"));
    table->setItem(1,0,new QTableWidgetItem("Date"));
    table->setItem(2,0,new QTableWidgetItem("Seconds"));
    table->setItem(3,0,new QTableWidgetItem("Source Date"));
    table->setItem(4,0,new QTableWidgetItem("Source Time"));
    table->setItem(5,0,new QTableWidgetItem("ServiceType"));
    table->setItem(6,0,new QTableWidgetItem("Transtype"));
    table->setItem(7,0,new QTableWidgetItem("UserId"));
    table->setItem(8,0,new QTableWidgetItem("UserIMSI"));
    table->setItem(9,0,new QTableWidgetItem("CorrelationId"));
    table->setItem(10,0,new QTableWidgetItem("MajorNumber"));
    table->setItem(11,0,new QTableWidgetItem("MinorNumber"));
    table->setItem(12,0,new QTableWidgetItem("Source Type"));
    table->setItem(13,0,new QTableWidgetItem("Total Consume"));
    table->setItem(14,0,new QTableWidgetItem("Source Info"));
    table->setItem(15,0,new QTableWidgetItem("Event"));
    table->setItem(16,0,new QTableWidgetItem("GroupID"));
    table->setItem(17,0,new QTableWidgetItem("ServiceID"));
    table->setItem(18,0,new QTableWidgetItem("OperatorId"));
    table->setItem(19,0,new QTableWidgetItem("Options Array"));

    table->resizeColumnsToContents();

    window->setCentralWidget(table);

    window->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

[image: Output of Table Widget]

Comment: Can you please add the compiler and version you are using as well as the Qt version?

Comment: Qt Version - Qt 5.2.0 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit) and Compiler - C++ 98

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QString test;

test = "a";

// First Column
table->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem(a));

// Second Column
table->setItem(0,1,new QTableWidgetItem(a));
```

just like that or:

```
// 100% working example
QVector< QString > string;
QVector< QString > value;

string.append( "Nr1" );
string.append( "Nr2" );
string.append( "Nr3" );
string.append( "Nr4" );

value.append( "1" );
value.append( "2" );
value.append( "3" );
value.append( "4" );

ui->twTable->setSortingEnabled( false );

for( int i = 0 ; i < string.size( ) && i < value.size( ) ; ++i )
{
    ui->twTable->insertRow( 0 );

    // First Column
    ui->twTable->setItem( 0 , 0 , new QTableWidgetItem( string[i] ) );

    // Second Column
    ui->twTable->setItem( 0 , 1 , new QTableWidgetItem( value[i] ) );
}

ui->twTable->setSortingEnabled( true );
```

`array` , `QStringList` work the same way just without the append.

array:

```
QString str[5] = { "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" };

for( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i )
{
    ui->twTable->insertRow( 0 );

    // First Column
    ui->twTable->setItem( 0 , 0 , new QTableWidgetItem( str[i] ) );

    // Second Column
    ui->twTable->setItem( 0 , 1 , new QTableWidgetItem( str[i] + QString::number( i ) ) );
}
```

QStringList:

```
QStringList str = { "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" };

for( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i )
{
    ui->twTable->insertRow( 0 );

    // First Column
    ui->twTable->setItem( 0 , 0 , new QTableWidgetItem( str[i] ) );

    // Second Column
    ui->twTable->setItem( 0 , 1 , new QTableWidgetItem( str[i] + QString::number( i ) ) );
}
```

And in reverse order:

```
// Probably the output you want:
QString str[5] = { "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" };

for( int i = 4 ; i >= 0 ; --i )
{
    ui->twTable->insertRow( 0 );

    // First Column
    ui->twTable->setItem( 0 , 0 , new QTableWidgetItem( str[i] ) );

    // Second Column
    ui->twTable->setItem( 0 , 1 , new QTableWidgetItem( str[i] + QString::number( i ) ) );
}
```

Remove the `ui->twTable->insertRow( 0 )` when you're using a fixed amount of rows like you do in your code.

Side note: I tend to disable sorting while inserting items and enabling it after so the rows don't get auto sorted to a different position when you input them.

Comment: I am trying to pass the names such as Sequence Number, Date etc., under Field Header. As u can see from the above code I am writing 20 times in this case, so how the I can achieve using an array so that I can pass all 20 names under 1st header.

Comment: @Chinmoy updated, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I was trying like this : QString str [5]= {"a", "b","c","d","e"};  or QStringList str[] = {"a","b","c","d","e"}. But anyway I will tryout with ur suggestion. So that If anyway we can pass to QTableWidgetItem(QString(str))

Comment: @Chinmoy what didn't work when you tried it this way?

Comment: @Chinmoy If you have C++11 available (C++11 compiler and `CONFIG += c++11` in the `.pro` file), you can write that using initializer lists: https://gist.github.com/webmaster128/07abec35e344c47a78e5

Comment: @dew1: I tried ur code, it is sorting in descending order. Thanx a lot, but I just want to declare an array either using QString,QStringList. For me as of now Vector is quite upper level. I am just looking at some low level.I will be glad if you can suggest in that way also.Thanx once again

Comment: @Chinmoy updated with what you want as well + in reverse order so the order is like you'd normally input it.

Comment: @SimonWarta good suggestion but i doubt he's ready to understand initializer lists yet :)

Comment: Good point. His compiler is not compatible anyway (MSVC2010).

Comment: @deW1 could you please suggest how I can auto-fill second column from a text file which contain comma separated values.

Comment: @Chinmoy read the file into a string and split it http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split